# Merging power tags

Tags: discussion, tags

[power](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power)
[power-supply](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-supply)
[alternative-power](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternative-power)

Shouldn't the tags above be merged?

Comment: #Yep Most of them have been already?

Answer (score 5):

The tags [power](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power) and [power-supply](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-supply) have been merged. I don't think that [alternative-power](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternative-power) and [power-supply](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-supply) should be merged though.

I think [power-supply](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-supply) should be used when talking about powering the Raspberry Pi or its peripherals using the standard micro-USB charger.

While [alternative-power](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternative-power) should be used when not talking about the micro-USB charger. Such as solar, wind, or PoE.

Comment: Do you really think alternative-power should be on its own?  It's possible it isn't broad enough to set itself apart from power-supply, and he number of questions that apply to alternative-power and not power-supply are rather few.

Comment: @jandjorgensen I really don't see how it hurts to have it.

Answer (score 3):

I created the [alternative-power](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternative-power) tag since alternative energy is quite a large sector which the raspberry pi would be good for diving into at an experimental and hobbyist level.

When I realised not everyone agreed, I removed the tag (since it was only on one post) however I fully support bringing it back and believe it could be very interesting if people choose to use it.